# Identity in Fourier summation

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose the following series:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k'}k'f_{k'}
\end{eqnarray}
where $f_{k'}$ are some Fourier coefficients that result from a periodic function $f(t+T)=f(t)$:
\begin{eqnarray}
f_{k'}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}dt e^{ik'2\pi t/T}f(t).
\end{eqnarray}
Is it true then that:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k'}k'f_{k'}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}dt e^{ik'2\pi t/T}f(t)\left(\sum_{k'}k'e^{ik'2\pi t/T}\right)=0,
\end{eqnarray}
that is, given that:
\begin{eqnarray}
g(t)=\left(\sum_{k'}k'e^{ik'2\pi t/T}\right)=2i\sum_{k'=1}^{+\infty}k'\sin(2\pi k' t/T)=0
\end{eqnarray}
Is the above identity correct?

**EDIT:** Wolfram Alpha gives the wrong answer for the sum $g(t)$. So I would like to know how to determine $g(t)$ in closed form, if possible.

Comment: The notation makes no sense unless $k'$ is an integer. If $k'$ is an integer that series is not a Fourier series

Comment: I forgot to mention that $k'$ is an integer, somehow I thought this would be obvious from the discrete summation. Why is this not a Fourier series? According to Wikipedia on FS, this has the same form as Eq.(4) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series. I also didn't say that the initial series is a Fourier series itself anywhere.

Comment: What??????????? How does $\sum_{k'} k'f_{k'}$ have the same form as $\sum c_ke^{2\pi inx/L}$? Your $f_{k'}$ is just a complex number, not an exponential function

Comment: You are confusing the initial sum, $\sum_{k'}k'f_{k'}$, which I agree is not of the Fourier form, with the last identity $\sum_{k'}k' e^{ik'2\pi t/T}$, which is of the Fourier form with $c_{k'}=k'$. The identity that eventually leads to the zero result is the last one, and that is the Fourier summation I am referring to.

Comment: I thought you were claiming that $\sum k'f_{k'}$ was a Fourier series, because it contains the Fourier coefficients. The series $\sum k'e^{ik'2\pi t/T}$ is not a Fourier series either, because it has nothing to do with $f$. And no, it's not "of the same form" as Eq 4 on Wikipedia; because $k'$ is not the Fourier coefficient of $f$.

Comment: "Of the Fourier form with $c_{k'}=k'$ is simply wrong. The point to Eq 4 is that $c_n$ is the Fourier coefficient of $f$.

Comment: And why do you think that $\sum_{k'=1}^{+\infty}k'\sin(2\pi k' t/T)=0$?

Comment: According to WolframAlpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/, the sum is identically zero, but I just want to know if this is correct.

Comment: If Wolfram alpha says that sum is zero it's wrong. It's a trig series with coefficients of polynomial growth, hence the Fourier series of a distribution, hence non-zero unless all the coefficients vanish. If you want to know what you did wrong try to give a link to a page where you've already entered this into WA.

Comment: [link to WA with the series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bn*Sin%5Bn*x%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2CInfinity%7D%5D)

Comment: well now we know you can't believe everything WA says

Comment: Ok, so considering this is wrong, which seems to be the case: how can one determine the distribution $g(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}k\sin(2\pi k/T)$ ? This seems to be a non-convergent sum, however $g(t+T)=g(t)$ by direct substitution, so $g(t)$ is a periodic function too.

Comment: Actually evaluating $\sum ke^{ikt}$ (with weal convergence!} turns out to be very easy. See Edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amplifying a bit @DavidCUllrich's answer: ... by the way, using $k'$ as a summing index is a bit confusing (in the context of standard practice) when there's no $k$ without the prime... Especially dangerous if/when derivatives might be involved.

So, somewhat revising the notation, first, we have $f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} \widehat{f}(k)\,e^{2\pi ikx}$, under various hypotheses on periodic $f$.

In circumstances where it is legitimate to differentiate termwise (e.g., either for fairly smooth $f$, or interpreting the summating as converging in a Sobolev space...)
$$
f'(x) \;=\; 2\pi i\cdot \sum_k k\cdot \widehat{f}(k)\cdot e^{2\pi ikx}
$$
Then, if this had a pointwise-convergence sense,
$$
\sum_k k\cdot \widehat{f}(k) \;=\; {f'(0)\over 2\pi i}
$$
much as in @DavidC.Ullrich's answer. Again, the notational choice is considerably distracting... :)

EDIT: I can't speak for any software system's reasoning about why $\sum_k k\cdot e^{2\pi ikx}=0$ (nor in what sense this is claimed), but it *is* true that $\sum_k 1\cdot e^{2\pi ikx}$ is a Fourier series expansion of the periodic Dirac delta, the Dirac comb. Of course this does not converge pointwise anywhere, but it does converge (meaningfully and usefully) in a Sobolev space.

The distributional derivative is indeed $2\pi i\sum_k k\cdot e^{2\pi ikx}$, and this is absolutely correct in a Sobolev space, and the differentiation is likewise absolutely correct, if interpreted properly.

Since the (distributional) derivative of the Dirac comb is locally $0$ away from integers, we might decide to say that the corresponding Fourier series is $0$ away from integers... and since the (distributional) derivative is locally $0$ away from integers, we could also say that the Fourier series for the derivative is $0$ there (even though it does not converge pointwise at all, only in a Sobolev space).

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, I understand this for a general periodic function f(t), but my concern is actually with evaluating $g(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}k\sin(2πkt/T)$, which seems to be not a convergent series, and why does WA say that g(t)=0 in this infinite sum.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is smooth then modulo some constant $$\sum_{k'}k'f_{k'}=cf'(0).$$

So your main question amounts to asking whether $$f'(0)=0$$holds for every periodic smooth $f$.

**Edit:** So now we want to know what distribution the series $\sum ke^{ikt}$ converges to. This turns out to be very easy. I'm going to take advantage of the Littlewood Convention, to the effect that $2\pi=1$; you may want to clean up the following, inserting the missing constants:

$\newcommand\D{\mathcal D}$
$\newcommand\T{\Bbb T}$
$\newcommand{\ip}[2]{\langle #1,#2\rangle}$

> > **Lemma** The series $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}e^{ikt}$ converges to $\delta_0$ in the (weak) topology of $\D'(\T)$.

Proof. Say $s_n=\sum_{|k|\le n}$. If $\phi\in\D(\T)$ then $$\ip{s_n}\phi=\sum_{|k|\le n}\widehat \phi(k)\to \phi(0)=\ip{\delta_0}\phi,\quad(n\to\infty)$$which is exactly what it means to say $s_n\to\delta_0$ in $\D'(\T)$.

And now since differentiation is continuous on $\D'(\T)$ it follows that $$i\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}ke^{ikt}=\delta_0',$$where by definition $$\ip{\delta_0'}\phi=-\phi'(0).$$

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I have a couple of questions though: What does $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{T})$ refer to? Secondly, are you defining $\delta_{0}\equiv\delta(t)$ as the delta distribution? If that is the case, then the evaluation of $\sum_{k}ke^{ikt}=\delta_{0}'$ is the derivative of the delta distribution: this should be zero everywhere except at $t=0$ if I am not mistaken. I also assume that $\langle f,g\rangle\equiv \int dt f(t)g(t)$ (?).

Comment: In fact, this all ammounts to calculating a series of the form: $\sum_{k}k u_{k}v_{k}$, where both $u_{k},v_{k}$ are obtained from $u_{k}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}dt e^{-ik2\pi t/T}u(t)$ and $v_{k}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}dt' e^{+ik2\pi t'/T}v(t')$, e.g both $u(t),v(t')$ are periodic functions. Then I get a summation of the form $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}k e^{+ik2\pi(t'-t)/T}=T\delta'(t'-t)$ according to your reply ?

Comment: @Zarathustra "the evaluation should be zero except at $t=0$": I don't know exactly what you mean by "the evaluation of the series". But I can't think of anything except the pointwise sum; if that's what you mean then no, the series is pointwise _divergent_. The terms don't even tend to zero. It's true that the sum  vanishes _in the sense of distributions_ on the complement of the origin...

Comment: @Zarathustra $\mathcal D(\Bbb T)$ is a standard notation for the infinitely differentiable functions ("test functions") on $\Bbb T$; the dual of this space is $\mathcal D'(\Bbb T)$, the space of distributions.

Comment: OK, let me put this in another way: Suppose we want to evaluate the sum$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}ku_{n+k}v_{n+k}$, with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and arbitrary integer, and where $u_{n+k},v_{n+k}$ are the Fourier coefficients of some arbitrary periodic functions $u(t),v(t)$. They can be written $u_{k}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}dt e^{-ik2\pi t/T}u(t)$ and $v_{k}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}dt e^{+ik2\pi t/T}v(t)$.  Using that one evaluates $\frac{1}{T^{2}}\int_{0}^{T}dt\int_{0}^{T}dt' u(t)v(t')\left[\sum_{k}ke^{i2\pi(n+k)(t'-t)/T}\right]$. Then the bracket is $Te^{i2\pi n (t'-t)/T}\delta'(t'-t)$? Is that correct?

Comment: @Zarathustra Assuming that by "the bracket" you mean $\langle u,v\rangle$ then no that's definitely not correct. The bracket is a _scalar_, not a function or a distribution!

Comment: No, the bracket refers to the expression between the [] brackets in my comment above.

Comment: @Zarathustra Sorry. Yes, that seems right offhand...